# Can CSS attribute selectors for boolean attributes be written more concisely?

Tags: html, css

I've read that HTML "[boolean attributes](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/#boolean-attribute)" such as *readonly*, *disabled*, *required* (etc.) can either be blank or have a value of their name. And people seem to be using both styles (see [How should boolean attributes be written?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7335974/how-should-boolean-attributes-be-written))...

So it seems that the best way to accommodate this is to write your CSS like:

```
input[readonly], input[readonly="readonly"] {
}
```

(https://stackoverflow.com/a/19644231/1766230)

But **is there a more concise way to write this?** Maybe using some CSS3 attribute selector magic? I've tried `input[readonly*=""]`, but without luck.

Comment: You only have to use `input[readonly]`... http://jsfiddle.net/FcBuS/

Comment: @JoshC ... You seem to be correct! I must have botched my earlier testing because I didn't think this worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As @JoshC writes in a comment, you can simply use `input[readonly]`. This CSS selector (which is ignorant of all markup serialization issues) matches an `input` element that has the `readonly` attribute, no matter what its value is. The XHTML (XML) requirement that every attribute specification must include a value does not affect this.

Answer (score 7):

Boolean values in HTML don't need an actual value. They are true if they exist and false if they don't.

However, In XHTML boolean values need to be set as a string that contains the name of the attribute set.

In HTML

```
<input ... readonly>
```

The CSS

```
input[readonly] { ... }
```

In XHTML which is annoying and I want to avoid at all costs

```
<input ... readonly="readonly" />
```

<s>The CSS</s>

```
input[readonly="readonly"] { ... }
```

**Edit:** As a lot of people point out, you can write just `readonly` in XHTML CSS since matching the *existence* of the attribute would work even if the attribute is set to something such as `readonly="readonly"`.

The CSS for XHTML is the same

```
input[readonly] { ... }
```

Unless you are using the CSS in both XHTML and HTML documents there is no need to write both forms of the selector. Just stick to HTML with `<input readonly>` and `input[readonly]`

Comment: There is no need to use the longer form even with XHTML.

Comment: I'm trying to think of a way to write the CSS so that it is portable and always valid (for modern browsers). It's valid HTML to have either just `readonly` or to have `readonly="readonly"`, so I don't want to assume one style over the other.

Comment: `[readonly]` is just an attribute selector.  If the attribute is set, regardless of its value or whether or not the attribute is valid, it will match.  Why do you have reason to believe it doesn't work?

Comment: Tested again and this does work. http://jsfiddle.net/luken/WBkLV/ Something must have been wrong with my initial test.